# MSBuild issue in cake script

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-3.5, cakebuild

We are compiling .net framework(2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.6) projects using cake script v0.18.0.

But, we are facing below issue while compiling 3.5 framework project

**MSBUILD : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.**

**Machine specification:**

1.VS 2017 professional

2.SDK 10

3..Net core 2.0.3

MSBuild compilation cake script code:

```
// Use MSBuild    
        MSBuild(projectFilePath, settings =>
            settings.SetConfiguration(configuration).
            WithProperty("referencepath" , refPath).
            SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal).
            SetNoConsoleLogger(true).
            WithProperty("PreBuildEvent" , "").
            AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger { LogFile = "../cireports/warnings/"+ filename +".txt",  MSBuildFileLoggerOutput = MSBuildFileLoggerOutput.WarningsOnly }).
            AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger { LogFile = "../cireports/errorlogs/"+ filename +".txt", MSBuildFileLoggerOutput = MSBuildFileLoggerOutput.ErrorsOnly}).
            WithProperty("CodeAnalysisRuleSet","\""+sourcedirInfo.FullName +@"\FxCop.ruleset"+"\"").
            WithProperty("StyleCopOverrideSettingsFile","\""+sourcedirInfo.FullName+@"\settings.StyleCop"+"\"").
            //UseToolVersion(toolsVersion).             
            WithProperty("OutputPath" , projoutputpath)); 

            //Deletes the empty error log file.
            if(FileExists("../cireports/errorlogs/"+ filename +".txt"))
                DeleteFile("../cireports/errorlogs/"+ filename +".txt");
            if(FileExists("../cireports/warnings/"+ filename +".txt"))
            {
                var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader("../cireports/warnings/"+ filename +".txt");
                var warnings = (streamReader.ReadToEnd()).Split('\r');
                streamReader.Dispose();
                if (warnings.Length-1 <= 0)
                //Deletes the empty warning log file.
                DeleteFile("../cireports/warnings/"+ filename +".txt");
                //Displays the errors & warnings count in console log.
                Information("\r\nCompilation result: {0} Error(s) {1} Warning(s)\r\n", 0, warnings.Length-1);
            }
```

Comment: Can you show the Cake Script you are using?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark,  Please find the msbuild compilation code added above.

Comment: @Karthi that wasn't really what I was asking for, but rather the Cake Script that is being used to call MSBuild.  I wanted to see what aliases are being used, and how they are being called.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Please check it now

Comment: @GaryEwanPark, Please check the cake script code now.

Comment: Nothing immediately stands out as needing changed.  If you take Cake out of the equation, and compile directly with MSBuild.exe, does everything work as you would expect?  If so, what is different between the command you run at the command line, and the command that is emitted by Cake?